# http://hows.info

Tags: discussion

What's with [hows.info](http://hows.info)?

---

> [image: image of hows.info]

---

It seems exactly the same as SO, except for two things:

- The logo is different
- I can't log in

Is this intentional? Does Stack Exchange know about it?

Additionally, it seems to have all of the pages that SO does:

- My user page: http://www.hows.info/users/1223693/doorknob
- The famous parsing of HTML with regex: http://www.hows.info/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/

I clicked "Ask Question" and it told me that I had to log in. Of course, I didn't put in my password (because that would be silly). When I tried to submit an answer, it said "An error occurred submitting the answer."

I'm assuming that it's not made by Stack Exchange. Why does it exist?

Comment: There are lots of SO clones...the goal is to use SO's content but their own ads to make free money.  That there are so many means that apparently the model works.

Comment: Wow it looks pretty current too.  If I look at the users page all the rep seems to line up.

Comment: It looks like the site literally copies the entire page as you would see it on Stack Overflow, but since it's a different domain, some things don't actually work.

Comment: Lol in the FAQ, are some screenshots with the SE name on it.

Comment: Yep a blatant copy - although they've tried to remove any mention of stack overflow, they forgot to change the favicon. :) @Servy: interestingly, I don't see any ads.

Comment: I'm already getting `Server not found` errors when i click on your links, and this question was just asked 6 minutes ago

Comment: @SamIam Interesting. They work fine for me.

Comment: The domain name hows.info is linked to somebody from Vietnam.

Comment: They link leader-board links back to `stackexchange.com` though. They didn't do a very good job of it.

Comment: Thankfully they don't seem to have a meta.hows.info... I can't see any meta link on the top..

Comment: It gets even more creepy. The JavaScript source code of Stack Exchange mentions that domain (www.hows.info) in encoded form. It got some relation, can't know what though.

Comment: @ShaWiz It's gone now. (Try visiting the site.)

Comment: @Doorknob yep it was a [failed attempt to block that illegal scraper](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176467/152859). :)