# JavaScript on whole site is broken in IE (9 or less) because of stub.js

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript, internet-explorer

Using IE 9 or less, I'm getting a JS error "Object is required" on line 1, position 137 in stub.js.

The script stops and the `StackExchange` object does not get initialized, so later there are "Object does not support this property or method" on calls to `StackExchange.init` etc. Basically nothing JS-related works.

The root of the error is this chunk of code:

```
if(window.location.host==atob("d3d3Lmhvd3MuaW5mbw==")
```

The function `atob()` is defined only starting at IE10. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11524268/447356).

Comment: Company firewall/proxy probably playing tricks blocking files.

Comment: What version of IE? Did you clear the cache? Does it happen with other browsers? Other versions of IE?

Comment: @Oded Does not happen in Firefox. Trying different IE versions now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Not really, got all files the page references.

Comment: Reproduced in IE7/IE8/IE9 browser modes in IE10. `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'atob': object is null or undefined`; `stub.js, line 1 position 137`.

Comment: @Pang true. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11524268/447356 and culprit code is `{if(window.location.host==atob("d3d3Lmhvd3MuaW5mbw==")`.

Comment: Interesting, some special *client side* code to handle some scrapers?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - No. This is an unintentional side-effect of trying to ban a scraper. Looking into this.

Comment: @Oded yeah, figured it after second look in the code. Cheers! :)

Comment: Reverting the change, will be back in working order in a few minutes.

Comment: @Oded why not post this as answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We are trying to block a scraper that is scraping against our terms & conditions.

This bug was an unforeseen consequence of trying to ban them client side - not realizing that atob is not supported by IE 7/8/9 (and 10 in 7/8/9 mode).

I am reverting the change and deploying as we speak.

Meta is back to normal now... as is the rest of the network.

Comment: You should blame [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-to-base64-using-javascript/247261#247261) for not letting you know.