# stackoverflow (and Meta.stackoverflow) broken on IE9, works on FireFox

Tags: bug, status-completed, internet-explorer-9

Both sites were working yesterday, but today my unanswered questions don't get colored for my Favorite Tags, clicking on "add comment" or upvoting a question just does nothing in IE, but works on FireFox (I'm asking this question using FF).
I did see this question ["JavaScript on whole site is broken because of stub.js"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176467/javascript-on-whole-site-is-broken-because-of-stub-js), but I get no Javascript errors.
Has something changed on the SO web sie?

Comment: (As an aside, it's simply "Firefox" with only one upper case F.)