# Hows Info. StackOverflow Rip

Tags: discussion, attribution, copycat-sites, screen-scraping

Complete rip with no attribution: `http://www.hows.info/`

related: [Report sites that use Stack Exchange content without following attribution rules here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-stack-exchange-content-without-following-attribution-rules)

Here is "me": `http://www.hows.info/users/561731/neal`

---

Now that it has been undeleted, go here to vote: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170787/155556

Comment: Ugh, they even use `sstatic.net` resources and steal the favicon.... still, I don't see why this shouldn't be an answer to the question you linked? What makes this special?

Comment: @Pekka웃 it seems to big for it, but if you think it belongs there i will move it there...

Comment: Looks like [the block stopped working then](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170787).

Comment: @animuson huh? I have no idea what that means...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: There's already a deleted answer on there for this exact same site. Anna had edited in a message that they were "blocked from our end."

Comment: @animuson well apparently not... They have my most recent reputation information (and question information etc...)

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA: That is from clear back on April 11. I'd guess they figured out how to get around the block.

Comment: @animuson the team tried to block it client side but the block caused the whole site to break in IE (`atob` is not supported by IE prior to 10), so [it was reverted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176470/152859) - guess they never found the time to write proper server side block. :(

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: In that case I've just undeleted that previous report since the "solution" is not valid

Comment: @animuson yup, well done. No doubt the worst of all, hope it can be dealt with on court and earn some money to SE!